# Pandas 2.0 pyarrow backend datetime operation

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pyarrow

I have the following pandas dataframe object using the pyarrow back end:

```py
crsp_m.info(verbose = True)

out:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4921811 entries, 0 to 4921810
Data columns (total 87 columns):
 #   Column             Dtype               
---  ------             -----               
 0   permno             int64[pyarrow]      
 1   secinfostartdt     date32[day][pyarrow]
 2   secinfoenddt       date32[day][pyarrow]
 3   securitybegdt      date32[day][pyarrow]
 4   securityenddt      date32[day][pyarrow]
```

I want to push back theses days to the month end similiar to what I did using the pandas datetime:

```py
crsp_m["date"] = pd.to_datetime(crsp_m.date)
crsp_m["date"] = crsp_m.date + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

What would be equavalent operation for `date32[day][pyarrow]` object?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just convert afterwards?

```
crsp_m["date"] = (pd.to_datetime(crsp_m.date) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0)).astype("date32[pyarrow]")
```